# How can I replicate a custom attribute from on-prem Active Directory to Azure AD?

Tags: active-directory, azure

I would like to display employee hire date as part of their profile info in SharePoint online.

I know that custom attributes can be created directly in SharePoint, but for other reasons I need to create the attribute in our local, on premises AD instance.

I've created a new attribute ("HireDate") on the user object in the Active Directory Schema, per [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20319.how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-in-active-directory.aspx). It shows up in the list of editable attributes when I go to edit someone's AD profile. So far so good.

Now I would like to include that attribute along with the other profile information that gets synced to our Azure AD, using the Azure Synchronization Service Manager.

I know how to include built-in attributes that are not synced by default (ex, [here](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/11/14/aad-connect-using-directory-extensions-to-add-attributes-to-azure-ad/)), but haven't found a way to do that with a custom attribute.

Comment: I could be off base, but it’s laid out pretty clearly in the article you linked to. Turn on directory extension syncing. Setup a new attribute to sync. Then simply clone the rule it makes as a template for your new rule and choose the proper source and target attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **directory extensions** to extend the schema in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) with your own attributes from on-premises Active Directory.

Select the attribute what you want to sync in the available attributes under the Directory extensions when you configure the AAD connect in the installation wizard.

[image]

Ref: [Azure AD Connect sync: Directory extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-feature-directory-extensions)

Comment: Thanks. I had gotten to this step, but the new custom attributes were not showing up. I had to refresh the schema for that to happen.